# Shortest way to create a List<T> of a repeated element

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, list

With the String class, you can do:

```
string text = new string('x', 5);
//text is "xxxxx"
```

What's the shortest way to create a List< T > that is full of `n` elements which are all the same reference?

Comment: Shortest in what sense? Smallest number of characters of code?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Try the following

```
var l = Enumerable.Repeat('x',5).ToList();
```

Comment: #Note: for reference type it results in a list of 5 references to *same* instance. E.g.: ```var l = Enumerable.Repeat(new SomeRefType(),5).ToList();``` will create single instance of `SomeRefType` & populate list with 5 references to this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way I know is:

```
int i = 0;
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

which you can make an extension method if you want to use it multiple times:

```
public void AddMultiple(this List<T> list, T obj, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        list.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
list.AddMultiple(obj, 5);
```

Comment: If you know the list length, set it during construction:
 var list = new List<MyObject>(5);

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty straight-forward ...

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { lst.Add( thingToAdd ); }
```

:D

Comment: I know how to do it. I said shortest.

Comment: I wasn't one to downvote you, btw. Easy mistake given I didn't say it in the title. Updated it :)

Comment: np ... I wonder what you definition of shortest is?  Minified?