# Java: Initialize collection (list) of size n > 1 with the same elements

Tags: java, collections, initialization

I would like to have a one-liner in Java like this:

```
List<A> list = initialize(element, n);
```

where element is of type A and n is an integer representing the wished size of the collection.

My original problem was to fill the list with the same reference without making copies of element, but also with copying is a good compromise.

Apache or Google collection utilities or similar are welcome. And if you think that this can be generalized to other java collections than lists, please add your comments.

Up to now that's my best solution (A is Boolean):

```
Lists.newArrayList(Arrays.copyOf(new Boolean[ ] { false }, n))
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120723/shortest-way-to-create-a-listt-of-a-repeated-element) (not on hold or closed) but it is not for java.

Comment: Do you want all the references in list refer to same object, or different objects?

Comment: Does `n` represent the number of elements that the list should contain? I assume that's what it's for but it wasn't expressly stated in the question.

Comment: @Sotirios I read the FAQ, what did I miss?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for [`Collections.nCopies(int, T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29).

Comment: +1 This is nCopies of the reference, not the object referenced.