# Fastest way to add a Range in a List C#

Tags: c#, list, optimization

I have to add about **3000** Elements to more than **20** Lists.
The code that I am using:

```
LastChange = new List<string>();
LastChange.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("/", 3000));

same for more than 20 Lists...
```

Is there any "fastest way" to add "/" to the Lists or that is the best solution. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: `LastChange = new List<string>(3000);` will be a little bit better: we allocate memory for `3000` items in order to avoid dynamic reallocation

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks. Could you please write the complete answer ?!

Comment: Why not [`LastChange = Enumerable.Repeat("/", 3000).ToList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120733/7831383)? I don't really get the point in using `AddRange` when your list isn't an existing list

Answer (score 3):

A bit better solution is to allocate memory for `3000` items in the constructor in order to avoid memory reallocation:

```
 LastChange = new List<string>(3000);

 LastChange.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("/", 3000));
```

You can go further and get rid of `IEnumerator<T>` in `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
 int count = 3000;

 LastChange = new List<string>(count);

 // compare to 0 is a bit faster then 3000
 for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
   LastChange[i] = "\";
```